# Getting Null value for the Page Object Element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am working in a cucumber , TestNG, Selenium based project and I have my PageObject page as below

```
package com.testing.pageobject;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.testing.components.SearchResultComponent;
import com.testing.stepdefinitions.BaseClass;

public class ShoppingPage extends BaseClass {



    public ShoppingPage(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
        super();
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='sh-dlr__list-result']")
    private List<SearchResultComponent> SearchResult;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='qa708e IYWnmd']")
    private List<WebElement> ResultListView;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='Ytbez']")
    private List<WebElement> ResultGridView;

    public List<SearchResultComponent> getSearchResult() {
        return SearchResult;
    }

    public List<WebElement> getResultListView() {
        return ResultListView;
    }

    public List<WebElement> getResultGridView() {
        return ResultGridView;
    }   

}
```

And my component page as below

```
package com.testing.components;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.testing.stepdefinitions.BaseClass;

public class SearchResultComponent extends BaseClass {



    public SearchResultComponent(RemoteWebDriver driver) {
         super();
         this.driver=driver;
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='AGVhpb']")
    private WebElement productName;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='O8U6h']")
    private WebElement productPrice;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='vq3ore']")
    private WebElement productStars;

    @FindBy(xpath="//img[@class='TL92Hc']")
    private WebElement productImage;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='hBUZL CPJBKe']")
    private WebElement productDescription;

    public WebElement getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public WebElement getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public WebElement getProductStars() {
        return productStars;
    }

    public WebElement getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public WebElement getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }




}
```

My cucumber step definition is

```
@When("search for product less than {int}")
public void search_for_product_less_than(Integer int1) {
    ShoppingPage myshopping = new ShoppingPage(driver);
    List<SearchResultComponent> SearchResults = myshopping.getSearchResult();
    for(SearchResultComponent myResult:SearchResults) {
        System.out.println(myResult.getProductName());
    }
}
```

Problem Statement :

I am getting null point error when I tried to get the getSearchResult() in the step definition. Not sure why any thoughts how to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure that exception occurres in `myshopping.getSearchResult()`? Not in the `for`  loop?

Comment: List<SearchResultComponent> SearchResults = myshopping.getSearchResult(); For SearchResults  itself i am geting null value , on passing in to for loop is the reason for this Null point error

Comment: I'd step through your code on `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`.  It's possible that it's not being initialized because it can't find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shoppingpage class use `WebElement` as type instead of class name `SearchResultComponent` as mentioned below.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='sh-dlr__list-result']")
private List<WebElement> SearchResult;

public List<WebElement> getSearchResult() {
    return SearchResult;
}
```

Also use webelement in cucumber step definition as well

```
   @When("search for product less than {int}")
   public static void search_for_product_less_than(Integer int1) {
        ShoppingPage myshopping = new ShoppingPage(driver);
        List<WebElement> SearchResults = myshopping.getSearchResult();
        for(WebElement myResult:SearchResults) {
            System.out.println(myResult.getText());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the needed element is not found in the page. This can have different reasons.

1) You call `new ShoppingPage(driver)` too early, when page fragment with `"//span[@class='qa708e IYWnmd']"` is not yet loaded.

2) It can be that the XPath is defined incorrectly and there is no such element on the page. Check your XPath.

Comment: Hi thanks for the update . I understood the reason but not sure how to get the  Product Name alone just by passing the SearchResult as a component to be iterated . I have crosschecked the xpath and its referring to the correct elements only. So it should not be an issue i Guess

Comment: There is no magic. If the attribute is null, it means that there is no such element on the page. You can check it by `driver.findElements(By.xpath("..."))`. Add such check temporarily before you call `new ShoppingPage(driver)`. If this direct search also returns null, it will confirm that either XPath is wrong or that the element really does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Yosuva A . I updated it to WebElement and its working now as below

```
public void search_for_product_less_than(Integer int1) {
    ShoppingPage myshopping = new ShoppingPage(driver);
    SearchResultComponent resultcomp = new SearchResultComponent(driver);

    List<WebElement> PriceResult = resultcomp.getProductPrice();
    List<WebElement> ProductName = resultcomp.getProductName();
    for(int i=0;i<PriceResult.size();i++) {
        String price = PriceResult.get(i).getText().replace("$", "");
        System.out.println("Price" + Double.valueOf(price));
        if(Double.valueOf(price)<13) {
            System.out.println(price);
            System.out.println(ProductName.get(i).getText());

        }
    }
}
```